# Create Dataframe from vector rowwise

Tags: r

Is there a way to create a dataframe from 2 vectors row wise?

```
list1<- c('a','b','c')
list2<- c('x','y','z')
```

I'd like to create a DF from these 2 lists such that each of these 2 lists is a row in the DF.

Comment: `data.frame(rbind(list1, list2))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is `data.frame`

```
data.frame(x = list1, y = list2)
#   x y
#1 a x
#2 b y
#3 c z
```

---

Or if it should be otherway, use `rbind`

```
setNames(rbind.data.frame(list1, list2), c("x", "y"))
```

Comment: no, out of the 2 suggestions you provided, 2nd one works fine. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user3510503 it is better to provide example that mimics the correct structure of your data.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use `bind_rows`

```
df <- bind_rows(x = list1, y = list2)
```

Output:

```
  x     y    
  <chr> <chr>
1 a     x    
2 b     y    
3 c     z
```